# Get Django-tastypie authenticated user details

Tags: django

I have implemented django project and it includes tastypie app. client can send the request to CRUD operations.

I have a problem with accessing logged user details. Here I'm trying to implement BasicAuthentication + TokenBased Authentication.

This is my custom implementation

```
from tastypie.authentication import Authentication
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization

class MyAuthentication(Authentication):

    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        return True

    from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
    if 'sessionid' in request.COOKIES:
        try:
            s = Session.objects.get(pk=request.COOKIES['sessionid'])
        except Exception,e:
            return False

        # get the user_id from the session
        if '_auth_user_id' in s.get_decoded():
            # try to find the user associated with the given sessionid
            try:
                u = User.objects.get(pk=s.get_decoded()['_auth_user_id'])
                if u is not None:
                    return False
            except Exception,e:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

    def get_identifier(self, request):
        return request.user.username
```

so then my resources file , I'm trying to access the `MyAuthenticate` class.

```
class InvoiceResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
        queryset = user.invoice_set.all()
        resource_name = 'invoice'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = MyAuthentication();
```

Here is the problem came up. I need to load all the invoices who belongs to logged user. basically I wanted to pass the logged user id as the parameter for this query.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

any idea?.

Answer (score 0):

See [Implementing Your Own Authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html) for the latest version. The cookbook (as of 4/18/2013) is outdated and uses `apply_authorization_limits` is is deprecated.

The new scheme is to create a custom authorization and apply that. The authorization can check whatever you want it to. In the docs, see `UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization` for an example of what you're talking about.